# How to change the number format of a short date format from English to Persian?

Tags: reactjs, date

I have a datepicker in reactJs with preselectedValue format in Persian like this:

[image]

When I choose a new date through Persian datepicker, it's a Persian date but in English numbers, like this:

[image]

I cant use `.toLocaleDateString('fa-IR')` for new selected value, it doesn't accept this. I just could use this method on preselectedValue that comes from `new Date()`. How can I have the second format like the first format?